# Does "&&" actually mean AND in AWK coding?

Tags: awk

I'm currently filtering out rows with a specific pattern from a large datafile. Because the rows need to meet several rules I use "&&" in awk. But I have the impression it is not exactly following a logical AND.

My data looks like:

```
    Group   EB1_D   EN1_D   EZ1_D   LB1_D   LN1_D   LZ1_D   MB1_D   MN1_D   MZ1_D   TB1_D   TN1_D   TZ1_D   AB1_D   AN1_D   AZ1_D
OG0008871:Down  0.886835651 NA  0.205991042 0.344286962 NA  0.212469765 0.934134739 NA  NA  0.087171422 0.144711362 0.002778751 NA  NA  NA
OG0021381:Down  0.65178744  0.000508521 0.477039947 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0.826395809 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
OG0011803:Up    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0.00734476  NA  NA  NA  0.458883104 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
OG0015725:Up    NA  NA  NA  NA  0.858766006 NA  NA  NA  NA  0.376378076 0.196034543 0.329094645 0.062600211 0.080328374 0.017079806
```

I want to filter out all rows where the B1_D are larger than any of the other values so I use the following (might not be the most practical but it should work anyway:

```
awk '$2 > $3 && $2 > $6 && $2 > $7 && $2 > $4 && $2 > $9 && $2 > $10 && $2 > $12 && $2 > $13 && $2 > $15 && $2 > $16 && $5 > $3 && $5 > $6 && $5 > $7 && $5 > $4 && $5 > $9 && $5 > $10 && $5 > $12 && $5 > $13 && $5 > $15 && $5 > $16 && $8 > $3 && $8 > $6 && $8 > $7 && $8 > $4 && $8 > $9 && $8 > $10 && $8 > $12 && $8 > $13 && $8 > $15 && $8 > $16 && $11 > $3 && $11 > $6 && $11 > $7 && $11 > $4 && $11 > $9 && $11 > $10 && $11 > $12 && $11 > $13 && $11 > $15 && $11 > $16 && $14 > $3 && $14 > $6 && $14 > $7 && $14 > $4 && $14 > $9 && $14 > $10 && $14 > $12 && $14 > $13 && $14 > $15 && $14 > $16 END {print $0}'
```

Applying this give only row OG0015725:UP as output However: 
one of the rules is $11 > $6. The value for $11 is 0.376378076 and for $6 is 0.858766006.

It should therefor not get selected, but it did. Did I perhaps apply this code wrongly?
Strangely OG0015725:UP is the last line of the input file and got selected in all my different output files!

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: (a) I get a syntax error, there's a semicolon missing before `END`. (b) Your `END {print $0}` prints the last line, not your ANDed conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, `&&` means AND in awk condition evaluation.

You didn't use it correctly, you should do something like:

```
awk '$1>$2 && $2 > $4{ some action }...' input
```

What you have:

```
awk '$1>$2 && $2 > $4 END{.action...}' input
```

If you want to use the short way to check and print current line:

```
awk '$1>$2 && $2 > $4; END{...}' input
```

btw, there must be a better way for your looooooooong check.

Comment: Yeah, I already got some suggestions to do it differently than in this long argument! But for now this works, thanks for the improvement!
One final issue I am facing now is that awk is seeing missing values or NA's as a positive result. So whenever it reaches the statement $1>$2 with NA>2 it will see it as a positive. How can I let AWK skip the NA's?

Comment: @T_R you can check if a value matching digits. In awk `"FOO">2` will be evaluated as `false` so will `"NA"`.

Answer (score 0):

here is a better approach than writing the chain `$1>$2 && $1>$3 && $1>$4`

```
awk 'function max(x,y) { return x>y?x:y }
     function maxof(xs) { n=split(xs,a); m=a[1]; for(i=2;i<=n;i++) m=max(m,a[i]); return m}
     $1 > maxof($2 FS $3 FS $4) {...'
```

valid since `x>y && x>z   <=>   x > max(y,z)`

Comment: this seems not to work for me yet. I get all lines as output, no selection. I assume I forgot to edit something where I should have done so? As command I copied everything exactly as given, correct?